# Magic Quotes runtime in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I have a live website on joomla 1.5 that has just gone blank. Both homepage and admin side.

The error log is showing magic quotes runtime error.

I have searched about it and as PHP new version has came out therefore it is causing problem.

How can I restore the website. So that I can upgrade to joomla 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix the problem is to ask your host to revert you to a previous PHP version since magic quotes no longer exists as of PHP 5.4. Some hosts have some .htaccess entries that will allow you to use a different version of PHP, but I'm not sure they will allow to revert to PHP 5.3 (or older) as these PHP versions are vulnerable.

Another way to fix the problem is to modify some core Joomla files (mainly the files using the `magic_quotes_gpc` function).